# MacBook Pro 2011 Server

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, command-line, osx-server

My 2011 Mbp has one of the ill fated AMD GPU's that through some clever work of the people on here is chugging along on its integrated GPU.

My question is there a way to set this up for future use as a headless server. requiring no gpu drivers to be loaded at all. because as it stands every time there is an update i have to manually remove the amd.kext files to get a bootable MBP. 
when MacOs rebuilds the kexts I can load single user mode to remove leading me to believe this is possible.

Is there a way to set up the MBP to be remotely accessible headless server for files and media? 
also would this allow me to update from Sierra?

Comment: A failed GPU doesn't change how you use your machine whether it's a personal laptop or server.  There are already a number of [questions/answers on this very topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=macbook+server).  It won't be headless as it has a screen physically attached to it - VNC will work just fine. Changing it to a server OS won't grant you the ability to upgrade to an OS that's not already supported by the OS - the 2011 MBP can upgrade to High Sierra.

Comment: I can’t upgrade because it rebuilds the kexts and starts a boot loop before it finishes the install Forcing me back to Sierra.